# upload file to s3 bucket using presigned url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

I am struggling to use the boto3 api to upload a file with a presigned url.

I see that there are quite a few questions but I still get an AccessDenied error.

I am following the boto3 documentation I even copied the function from the docs, but still getting the error, see [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html)

```py
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from botocore.config import Config
import requests    
from pprint import pprint
config = Config(signature_version="v4")
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=config)


def create_presigned_post(bucket_name, object_name,
                          fields=None, conditions=None, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL S3 POST request to upload a file

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param fields: Dictionary of prefilled form fields
    :param conditions: List of conditions to include in the policy
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Dictionary with the following keys:
        url: URL to post to
        fields: Dictionary of form fields and values to submit with the POST
    :return: None if error.
    """

    # Generate a presigned S3 POST URL
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name,
                                                     object_name,
                                                     Fields=fields,
                                                     Conditions=conditions,
                                                     ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL and required fields
    return response
def create_bucket(s3_bucket_name):
    response = s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, CreateBucketConfiguration={
    'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-2'})
    pprint(response)



key_name = 'italian_spiderman.jpg'
bucket_name='italian-spiderman-bucket'
# create_bucket(bucket_name)


response = create_presigned_post(bucket_name, key_name)
print(response)
if response is None:
    exit(1)

# Demonstrate how another Python program can use the presigned URL to upload a file
with open(key_name, 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': (key_name, f)}
    http_response = requests.post(response['url'], data=response['fields'], files=files)
    print(http_response)
    pprint(http_response.text)
# If successful, returns HTTP status code 204
logging.info(f'File upload HTTP status code: {http_response.status_code}')
```

The bucket has default configuration (no cors, public access blocked, default encryption)
the role I am using to do this has `s3:*` permissions.

I have also tried adding some more stuff in like cors, bucket policy and removing block to public access.

Still access is denied.

===========UPDATE===========

tried this with an account and role with admin access and works. so the question is, what permission do I need on the role to upload?

Comment: You would need `PutObject()` permission on the credentials used when the above code is running, for the target bucket. What permissions do the credentials currently have?

Comment: the role I was using had "s3:*" permission. To make it work I had to had resource permissions on the s3 bucket. but on the machine with admin role, I did not do that and worked. so I still don't get it. I am using the same code

Comment: You are using the same code, but you are using **different credentials**. An `Access Denied` error is related to permissions, not code. So, it would seem that the credentials being used do not have sufficient permissions. Can you Edit your question to show the permissions associated with the IAM User / IAM Role that caused the `Access Denied` error? Also, if it is an IAM Role, please tell us how the role is generated, because the permissions associated with the pre-signed URL would only be valid for the same duration as the IAM Role (which might be the cause of your problem).